# Xcode conversion to Swift 4 from older versions, causes Argument labels overload issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

If I apply the automatic migration to Swift 4 proposed by Xcode, I get the error
***Argument labels '(jsonDictionary:)' do not match any available overloads***

The error happens on the line

```
let jsonObject = JSON(jsonDictionary: jsonRequest)
```

of this code:

```
let jsonRequest = [
            "requests": [
                "image": [
                    "content": imageBase64
                ],
                "features": [
                    [
                        "type": "HOUSE",
                        "results": 100
                    ],
                    [
                        "type": "GARAGE",
                        "results": 90
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        let jsonObject = JSON(jsonDictionary: jsonRequest)

        // Serialize the JSON
        guard let data = try? jsonObject.rawData() else {
            return
        }
```

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Comment out the line (`//`), type `JSON(` and use code completion to find the appropriate API.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved editing the line

```
let jsonObject = JSON(jsonDictionary: jsonRequest)
```

in

```
let jsonObject = JSON(jsonRequest)
```